# Immersive Reader hangs on certain content

Tags: azure, immersive-reader

For certain content, Microsoft Immersive Reader stops reading aloud and hangs on a script error.

- Can someone reproduce this/confirm that this is indeed a bug?
- If so, suggest a workaround to avoid it?

The problems occurs when I

- load and initialize the SDK from https://ircdname.azureedge.net/immersivereadersdk/immersive-reader-sdk.1.3.0.js
- call ImmersiveReader.launchAsync with a data chunk containing the sample text below

Sample text (errors occur both for this plain text string, as for the original html from wikipedia):

> Romeo and Juliet is a tragedy written by William Shakespeare early in
> his career about two young star-crossed lovers whose deaths ultimately
> reconcile their feuding families. It was among Shakespeare's most
> popular plays during his lifetime and along with Hamlet, is one of his
> most frequently performed plays. Today, the title characters are
> regarded as archetypal young lovers.\nRomeo and Juliet belongs to a
> tradition of tragic romances stretching back to antiquity. The plot is
> based on an Italian tale translated into verse as The Tragical History
> of Romeus and Juliet by Arthur Brooke in 1562 and retold in prose in
> Palace of Pleasure by William Painter in 1567. Shakespeare borrowed
> heavily from both but expanded the plot by developing a number of
> supporting characters, particularly Mercutio and Paris. Believed to
> have been written between 1591 and 1595, the play was first published
> in a quarto version in 1597. The text of the first quarto version was
> of poor quality, however, and later editions corrected the text to
> conform more closely with Shakespeare's original.\nShakespeare's use
> of his poetic dramatic structure (especially effects such as switching
> between comedy and tragedy to heighten tension, his expansion of minor
> characters, and his use of sub-plots to embellish the story) has been
> praised as an early sign of his dramatic skill. The play ascribes
> different poetic forms to different characters, sometimes changing the
> form as the character develops. Romeo, for example, grows more adept
> at the sonnet over the course of the play.\nRomeo and Juliet has been
> adapted numerous times for stage, film, musical, and opera venues.
> During the English Restoration, it was revived and heavily revised by
> William Davenant. David Garrick's 18th-century version also modified
> several scenes, removing material then considered indecent, and Georg
> Benda's Romeo und Julie omitted much of the action and added a happy
> ending. Performances in the 19th century, including Charlotte
> Cushman's, restored the original text and focused on greater realism.
> John Gielgud's 1935 version kept very close to Shakespeare's text and
> used Elizabethan costumes and staging to enhance the drama. In the
> 20th and into the 21st century, the play has been adapted in versions
> as diverse as George Cukor's 1936 film Romeo and Juliet, Franco
> Zeffirelli's 1968 version Romeo and Juliet, and Baz Luhrmann's 1996
> MTV-inspired Romeo + Juliet.

The Immersive Reader opens correctly, and shows all text. But when I start the reader, reading aloud stop after the phrase 'grows more adept at the sonnet over the course of the play.'

When you click on the text below that phrase, as script error occurs

- in https://ircdname.azureedge.net/static/main-705e61ade60c43447d2b.min.js
- in the function setActiveLineHeight, where this._selectedExpression.line is undefined, so this._selectedExpression.line.height throws an exception.